# Applets- How to get out of the Sandbox? (JAVA)

Tags: java, applet

I have made an applet however I have found out that it is in a tight "sandbox"
I don't exactly understand this, but what I do understand is that I have to get out of it writing code.

However I have no idea whatsoever how to do that.

I get this in my Java console:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied    ("java.io.FilePermission" "Map_F.png" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.canRead(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at code.Loop.run(Loop.java:32)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My code is here at Github:
https://github.com/KultidGames/Brandish/tree/master/Game_01/src/code

This might also help:

```
public void run() {
    x = 100;
    y = 100; //1:50 if Background wanted http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dabnz7NSiUc
    try {
    fore = ImageIO.read(new File("Map_F.png"));
    map = ImageIO.read(new File("Map.png"));
    rle = ImageIO.read(new File("MainCharRightRun.png")); //c
    rri= ImageIO.read(new File("MainCharLeftRun.png"));//-
    wup= ImageIO.read(new File("MainChar.png"));//c
    wdo= ImageIO.read(new File("MainCharRunBack.png"));//-
    wright=ImageIO.read(new File("MainCharLeft.png"));//c
    wleft=ImageIO.read(new File("MainCharRight.png"));//-
    back=ImageIO.read(new File("MainCharStill.png"));//c
    still=ImageIO.read(new File("MainCharBack.png"));//-
    rs= ImageIO.read(new File("MainCharLeftStill.png"));//c
    ls= ImageIO.read(new File("MainCharRightStill.png"));//-
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Note I removed your link to your other question. Let's keep things pure and straightforward here.

Comment: The sandbox is part of Java's security system, which I strongly suggest you read up on. In general, applets are NOT trusted code and are not given free access to the user's system, for very obvious reasons. Redesigning to not require that access is the preferred solution. Signing will let the user authorize your applet to perform additional actions, IF they are willing to trust you -- but frankly, from what I've seen of your code above, that isn't the right answer in this case; a game has no need for access to the user's box.

Comment: @keshlam: thanks. This way the OP will be notified of your comment's existence, and it will have a better chance of being read.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no clue how to remove the applet.
everything gets errors.

Comment: @Kultid_Games: what do you mean by `"I have no clue how to remove the applet."` -- as out of context, this makes little sense.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what I meant there.
However, how so do you mean packaging my images?
And how would I go about doing so?

Again, I am a beginner, I've yet to learn much about this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of struggling upstream, I suggest that you consider packaging your images in your Jar file and then accessing them as resources. Do this and there's no need to "get out of the sandbox". As keshlam notes below, the sandbox is there for a very good reason -- for computer security so that applets will not have the ability to have access to things they shouldn't have access to.

Comment: Another approach is to put the un-Jarred images in a place from which they can be accessed by an `URL` relative to the document base or code base of the applet.  This has both pluses and minuses.  A) Advantage:  It allows that applet to load prior to loading the images. B) Disadvantage: It causes more HTTP calls to get all the images. -- It is neither here nor there in terms of compression, since Zip/Jar compression usually does nothing for compressed media types like PNG.  Accessing the images relative to code base or document base also allows the images to be loaded while sand-boxed.